# Can an instance profile resource in Terraform have multiple inline policies?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to convert a Cloud Formation script to Terraform. One of the issues I'm running into in the script
Cloud Formation:

```
"Resources": {
"*******InstanceProfile": {
    "Condition": "IsInstanceProfile",
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Policies": [
            {
                "PolicyName": "********-*******-instance",
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Resource": [
                                {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/${ReadOnlyRole}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWSOrganizationsAccountID}:role/${OrganizationsRole}"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "RoleName": {
            "Ref": "AccessName"
        }
    }
}
```

I am ASSUMING I can use an inline_policy within a resource like in [aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role). Here is my Terraform snippet that I've produced but get errors:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "*****_instance_profile" {

 

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({

    Version = "2012-10-17"

    Statement = [

      {

        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"

        Effect = "Allow"

        Sid    = ""

        Principal = {

          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"

        }

      },

    ]

  })

 

  policy = jsonencode({

    Version = "2012-10-17"

    Statement = [

        Action   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

        Effect   = "Allow"

        Resource = "arn:aws:iam::*:role/${ReadOnlyRole"

     

    ]

  })

}
```

I guess I'm stuck with adding the resource within the policy. How would anyone handle this conversion? Do you folks think I'm going down the correct path with aws_iam_role? And, if so, how would you handle multiple resources in an inline_policy?

Comment: "but get errors" - what errors? Your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: You're getting down-votes for saying you "get errors" without including those errors in your question. On StackOverflow you should **always** include the exact details of your errors in the question. Also your question was phrased in a very generic way "can a Terraform resource have multiple policies" when that answer is of course going to be tied to the specific type of resource you are creating. In this instance "can an AWS instance profile in Terraform have multiple policies" is a much clearer and more appropriate way to phrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the official documentation when adding multiple resources to a policy.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {

    actions = [
      "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::*",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/home/&{aws:username}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/home/&{aws:username}/*",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  name = "test-user"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "test-policy"
  description = "A test policy"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.user.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```